# Bigquery - Join giving wrong result

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to join two tables in BigQuery.

```
select p.UserId UserId , SessionMonth, LifeCycle, f.NetRev NetRev
from TABLEA p
left join each TABLEB f
on p.UserId = f.UserId
```

For some reason, f.NetRev in the join is doubled.

Here is the job id: 719125837414:job_Kotq0SggPq8xtgUGOu5p6yR9Ag0.

It would be great if someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: The job id you gave is from a very complex query. Can you reproduce this with a simpler query? That would make it much easier to follow up. Also, please make sure you're not seeing a join key on the left matching with two keys on the right side of the join, which could cause doubled output.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that the table you're joining against doesn't have any repeated keys. That is, if you're joining a table that has two rows:

```
{A, 1}
{B, 2}
```

and another table that that has

```
{B, foo}
{B, bar}
```

and you do a left join on the first with the second on the first column column of both, you'll get more rows than you started out with:

```
{A, 1, null}
{B, 2, foo}
{B, 2, bar}
```

(worst case this can generate N x M rows where N is the number of rows in the first table and M is the number of rows in the right table).

If you're certain that the join is really behaving incorrectly, it may be a bigquery bug.  If so, please add a comment and we'll look further (for example, looking your job id up in the logs, it looks like you also use analytic functions (`LAG()` and `LEAD()`). Can you try without those and make sure the issue still reproduces?)

Comment: Hey I am pretty sure the keys are not repeated. I had another look of the query. It seems like the wrong result appears when there are tables from different projects and not all project ids of the tables are specified. Here are two job ids:  **719125837414:job_CHo_1hOFMBbxRl2fBLQ9URhjKUg** (no project id), **719125837414:job_mJXH-fpoEEqubrZsRzhOcOUxaaE** (with all project ids). But adding project ids to all the tables should solve the problems for now I guess. Thanks!